# GKE service account for Node Pools

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, service-accounts

it is not possible to Update Service Account which benig used by Node Pools on existing GKE Cluster?
seems like its only possible when creating new Nodepool and not by updating existing ones.

also, how does this works with Node Auto Provisioning?
any chance this will require recreation of the Cluster?

10x

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, it is only possible to assign a Service Account to new Node Pools at the moment of creation, e.g. using the corresponding `gcloud container node-pools create` command with the `--service-account` flag as per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/node-pools/create).

Just for comparison, we can see that this option is not present on the `gcloud container node-pools update` command [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/node-pools/update) on how to update a Node Pool.

Regarding how it works with Node auto-provisioning, it applies the same principle: you can update the cluster configuration without recreating it, enable auto-provisioning, and specify the Service Account that will be used when auto-provisioning creates **new** Node Pools, but you cannot modify it in existing Node Pools.

You can set it up like this as showed in its [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/node-auto-provisioning#identity) as well:

```
gcloud container clusters update CLUSTER_NAME \
    --enable-autoprovisioning --autoprovisioning-service-account=SERVICE_ACCOUNT
```